opensearch 2.13.0 read billion docs
I want to pull billions of docs from opensearch, i tried point-in-time with search after however i don’t see a good performance. Lets say 5 million takes 6.5 hrs to pull in a batch of 1000, anything more gets timedout. Is there a better approach to pull billion records in a reasonable time.
